# allow access to all resources on kubernetes cluster except get nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

Team, I have below cluster role on kubernetes that allows access to everything but I wan't to restrict node level commands and allow all rest.

What to modify below?
Basically, user should be able to run

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

but not nodes info should NOT display

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: cluster-admin-test
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - '*'
    resources:
      - '*'
    verbs:
      - '*'
  - nonResourceURLs:
      - '*'
    verbs:
      - '*'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rules are purely additive, means that you cannot restrict rules.

Thus, you will need to list all accessible [resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#resource-types), but "nodes" with appropriate [operations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#operations)

For example:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: cluster-admin
rules: 
- apiGroups: [""] 
  resources: ["pods","services","namespaces","deployments","jobs"] 
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Also, it is highly not recommended to change **cluster-admin** role.
It is worth to create a new role and assign users to it.

Comment: so this again, allows all access except access to nodes level operations? like user won't be able to perform 
   ` kubectl delete node`

Comment: @fmaabd this will allow access only to those resources, which were explicitly mentioned in your cluster role rules, i.e.["pods","services","namespaces","deployments","jobs"]